# Is there identity conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

The title says it all. I've seen that some people apparently use `Data.Conduit.List.map id` as identity conduit, but is this the recommended way to stream data unchanged?

Comment: Judging from `Data.Conduit.List.map` implementation, i'd say yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to write an identity conduit is probably:

```hs
awaitForever yield
```

because this doesn't require an extra import.

The definition of `Data.Conduit.List.map` is very similar:

```hs
mapC f = awaitForever $ yield . f
```

(The difference between `mapC` and `map` has something to do with CPP macros to define fusion.)

When optimization is on (`-O1`), it appears both options result in identical code, so it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: It would be cool if `idC = awaitForever yield` were added to the library. Maybe I will create a PR for this.

Comment: @Mark any news regarding the PR?

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake, please see https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/issues/255